# Get collection with filters - getName is null

Tags: magento2

I can get the collection, but something is wrong. First, I created a Module to load a product collection:

```
app/code/{Name}/RandProducts/Block/Randproductlist.php
<?php

namespace {Name}\RandProducts\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Randproductlist extends Template
{
    private $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
       Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
       array $data = array()
    ){
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
       $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
       $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getRandomProducts($categoryId) {

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->load();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(*);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

At this point if i go to my phtml in my theme and do:

### Random Products

```
<?php
    $productList = $block->getRandomProducts();

    foreach ($productList as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getName());
        var_dump($product->getSku());
        var_dump($product->getId());
    }
?>
```

I can see the sku, and the id but the name is null (and in the backend if i look for the product filter by sku it have name).

But i want to add filters,and, if it's possible, get only 5 random products, so i add in getRandomProducts, before return:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'subtitle', 'image', 'url'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_saleable', '1')
        ->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

and... nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Replace **getRandomProducts** following code:

```
public function getRandomProducts()
{

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    return $collection;
}
```

Get random product, try following way:

```
public function getRandomProducts()
{

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(5)->orderRand();
    return $collection;
}
```